# How to continue program if catch JsonParse error

Tags: json, scala, try-catch, json4s

First of all - sorry for stupid question.
I got some Json string from DB and want to parse all of them with json4s:

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM analytic.test").repartition(22)
val df_base = df.map(f => {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  val jsonString = f(5).toString
  val tempJSON = parse(jsonString)
  val mainJsonArray = tempJSON \ "events"
  (
    f(2).toString,
    makeEventArray(mainJsonArray)
  )
}).cache()
```

All good, i got Json's, but sometimes in DB occurs some failed Json, that take me to error :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing '"' for name
```

**First question** - How can I evade this row with corrupt Json and continue my program?

I trying surround *parse* with try\catch, but in this case:

```
var tempJSON = json4s.JsonAST.JValue
try {
  tempJSON = parse(f(5).toString)
} catch {
  case e: Exception => println("Error on JSON parser. " + e )
}
```

But taking error:

```
Error:(51, 25) type mismatch;
found: org.json4s.JValue (which expands to) org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue
required: org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue.type tempJSON = parse(f(5).toString)
                                                 ^
```

**Second question** - How to declare tempJson right?

---

Or I must validate Json before parse? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Try` for it:

```
val tempJSON = Try(parse(f(5).toString))
```

So now, you can `match` it:

```
tempJSON match {
  case Success(yourValue) => ???
  case Failure(exception) => println(exception.getMessage)
}
```

Or, if you don't need the exception, you would convert it to `Option`:

```
tempJSON.toOption
```

You'll get `None` or `Some(value)`.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `json4s` but it probably exists, like in `Play Json`, a `validate` function returning something like a `JsError` or a `JsSuccess`.

Otherwise, an other way to go is to return an `Option[JValue]` (if you don't want to deal with exceptions), i.e. :

```
def function: Option[JValue] = {
  try {
    Option(parse(f(5).toString))
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => None
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all parsing errors and silently skip them, which is risky and ill advised in most cases. 
You can simply do:

df.flatMap(f => Try(do something).toOption)

You may however prefer, earlier validation preventing this to begin with, catching a more specific error only, logging errors etc.